# How to select record except those that match the join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In our webapps, an employee can perform one or more jobs at the same time, so the database is structured like this:

http://rextester.com/VTFND62465

table `tma_employee`:

```
emp_id | emp_name
-------|---------
1      | BOB
2      | MAX
3      | SALLY
```

table `tma_job`:

```
job_id | job_name
-------|---------
1      | DEV
2      | SALES
3      | MGMT
```

relation table between employees and jobs `tma_employee_job`:

```
emp_id | job_id
-------|-------
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 2
2      | 3
3      | 3
3      | 1
```

Given this structure, it is easy to select all employees which perform one or more specific jobs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*
FROM tma_employee E
JOIN tma_employee_job EJ USING (emp_id)
JOIN tma_job J USING (job_id)
WHERE J.job_name = 'DEV';
```

However, how can I select all employees which do **not** perform that job?

I tried inverting the condition like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*
FROM tma_employee E
JOIN tma_employee_job EJ USING (emp_id)
JOIN tma_job J USING (job_id)
WHERE J.job_name != 'DEV';
```

However this does not work because, for example, BOB is also on the SALES job, which is different from DEV, so employee BOB is found from the above query.

I have also found that this works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*
FROM tma_employee E
WHERE E.emp_id NOT IN (
    SELECT EJ.emp_id
    FROM tma_employee_job EJ
    JOIN tma_job J USING (job_id)
    WHERE J.job_name = 'DEV'
);
```

However, it requires me to use a subquery, which I would like to avoid, because the main query is built by a function which, based on the parameters it receives, starts from `SELECT E.* FROM tma_employee E` and then adds all the various JOINS and clauses.

Is it possible to obtain the same result of the query which uses the sub-query, while sticking to simple JOINS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/KPLC27547)** without subquery:

```
SELECT E.emp_id, E.emp_name
FROM tma_employee E
LEFT JOIN tma_employee_job EJ USING (emp_id)
LEFT JOIN tma_job J ON J.job_id = EJ.job_id
GROUP BY E.emp_id, E.emp_name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN job_name = 'DEV' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: I think you nailed it!

Comment: This seems to work correctly and is easy to manage with a query builder function... I'll try it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*
FROM tma_employee E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EJ.emp_id
    FROM tma_employee_job EJ
    JOIN tma_job J USING (job_id)
    WHERE J.job_name = 'DEV'
) T ON E.emp_id = T.emp_id 
WHERE T.emp_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Works, but still uses subqueries, which I'd like to avoid

Comment: @MatteoTassinari That isnt really a subquery, is a derivated table. And shouldnt be any problem in performance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you are right, my problem here is not performance, but the function which dinamically creates the query string, which is already complex enough ... it may also be that I cannot solve this problem the way I'd like.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I can understand if this is a simplified sample, but here dont see the need for a dinamic query, Creating a Store Proc sound more logic.

Comment: It is very much simplified, yes, I just isolated one specific aspect, but in reality the JOINS can be up to 12, with many search parameters and conditions